Azure Event Hubs Schema Registry Error SubCode 40504 "conflicted with another request"
I am occasionally getting the error below when my .NET 8 Azure Functions app is trying to send events to my Event Hubs instance that is using Avro with Schema Registry:

SubCode=40504, Request on entity [EntityName] in group [GroupName]
conflicted with another request. Wait for current request to complete.
SubCode=40901. To know more visit
https://aka.ms/sbResourceMgrExceptions. . TrackingId:[TrackingId],
SystemTracker:[SystemTracker], Timestamp:[Timestamp] Status: 409
(Conflict) ErrorCode: ErrorInRequest

What does "wait for the current request to complete" mean?  Is my Azure Function trying to update the Schema Registry in my Event Hubs maybe?  It should only ever be reading from there.

I think I found the culprit in this line of code:
private readonly SchemaRegistryAvroSerializer _serializer = 
    new(schemaRegistryClient, 
        config["EventHubs:SchemaRegistryName"], 
        new SchemaRegistryAvroSerializerOptions { AutoRegisterSchemas = true });

The AutoRegisterSchemas=true meant I was trying to both read to and write from the Schema Registry, when I only want to read.  The default for this setting is false.  Once I removed that, the error went away.
